# Lightbox - Next and Prev buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

So I'm using this lightbox and I need to put Next and Previous buttons, but I don't know how. If someone can help me...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.lightbox').click(function () {
          // Get all following .box and .background until next .lightbox is met.
          // So we can get the related contents.
          var $targets = $(this).nextUntil('.lightbox', '.box, .background');
            $targets.animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 500, 'linear')

            $targets.filter('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 500, 'linear');

            $targets.css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('.background, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 500, 'linear', function () {
                $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
            });;
        });

        $('.background').click(function () {
            $('.background, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 500, 'linear', function () {
                $('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
            });;
        });
    });
```

Here > https://jsfiddle.net/cuummyhx/

Comment: I think you can use already created plugins, that will allows you to just customize it in a few minutes and "BOOM" use it :)

Like "iLightBox plugin" or "andreknieriem.de/simple-lightbox/".

If you want to write your own lightbox, then question is deeper then just add two buttons next and prev, you'll spend a lot of time for this to create good structured code & well markup it + test it.

There is a pretty much lessons on how to code own lightbox, you should choose it by your own because they have different level of difficulty.

Comment: Tks for the tip @MaksymSulym